# Create a config file for ssh command

Tags: ssh

I have a ssh command as below:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh ubuntu@ip_addr -W %h:%p" ubuntu@ip_addr2 -L port:ip_addr3:port
```

I want to create a config file for this command, but I don't know what is the option of `-L`, here is my config file so far:

```
Host cassandra-khatkesh
  User ubuntu
  Hostname ip_addr2
  ProxyCommand ssh ubuntu@ip_addr -W %h:%p
```

Anyone knows how can I add `-L` to config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-L` corresponds to the `LocalForward` keyword.

```
Host cassandra-khatkesh
  User ubuntu
  Hostname ip_addr2
  ProxyCommand ssh ubuntu@ip_addr -W %h:%p
  LocalForward port ip_addr3:port
```

Note that the local and remote endpoints are specified separately, not as  single `:`-delimited string.